# Is there any switch to adjust the amount limit of file descriptors for sendmsg?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

On my system (os: fedora20, kernel: 3.19.8). 
I use `sendmsg` to send file descriptor, when amount of fds is over 253, the sendmsg will return `EINVAL`. Is there any switch to adjust the amount limit of fds?

This is the arguments I used when I'm calling sendmsg, I'm using strace utility to grab this information below...

when the amount of fds is lower or equal to 253, the `sendmsg` is ok.

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"!", 1}], msg_controllen=1028, 
[{
cmsg_len=1028, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, 
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256]
}],
msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1
```

when the amount of fds is more then 253, the `sendmsg` will return `EINVAL`

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"!", 1}], msg_controllen=1032,
[{
cmsg_len=1032, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS,
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257]
}],
msg_flags=0}, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Comment: What's the numeric value in your system's  `/proc/sys/net/core/optmem_max` ?

Comment: I tried to modify the it, but does not work. On my system the value of /proc/sys/net/core/optmem_max is 20480

Comment: Looks like 253 is a hardwired limit. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/scm.h#L13 and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/scm.c#L79 . I don't know offhand if it's safe to increase the #define and recompile the kernel.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick It seems you are right, thanks a lot! :D